# Need to call 2 static resources in CSS and Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, css, static-resources

We are using a Static resource (say ABC) to store all css and images and this static resource is being called on a VF page. Now due to size limit (5 MB) of Static Resource and need to modify the static resource which will increase the size of Static Resource. Please suggest what could be an appropriate solution to caters this. We were thinking of taking few large image files out of this Static Resource (ABC) and create another one (XYZ) and map it with VF page. But we are unsure how we are going to refer this new Static resource in css and in VF page. P
Please suggest.

Comment: The awkward case is where CSS in one static resource needs to reference an image in another static resource. (Direct references in Visualforce can use $Resource but static resources do not go through the processing that replaces that.) Is that awkward case required?

Comment: Due to space crunch, we thought of implementing this change. What could be the best possible solution.

Comment: Before this awkward change, run your images through https://tinypng.com/ or https://tinyjpg.com/. Most image files are left way bigger than they need to be. Will also result in quicker transfer from server to browser.

Comment: We have already compressed the images and compressing further will result in distorted images. Could you please help me with any other options